# Output model from GLM in R

Tags: r, regression, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression

I had generate in **R**a logistic model using *glm* using binomial as family, but each session that I started in **R** the variable that I used to store the glm output gives me another output. 
Why this happen? Why **R** didn’t save/store the output from *glm* in the variable that I created for.
I’ve been googling for an answer, but I didn’t find anything, so maybe you could help me to understand.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't describe exactly what you did so it's impossible to tell you what happens, but anyway relying on R saving the workspace is not the best option to save your model. It would be much safer to actually save the model to a file, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5118074/891919) for instance:

> ```
> > set.seed(345)
> > df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20))
> > df <- transform(df, y = 5 + (2.3 * x) + rnorm(20))
> > ## model
> > m1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
> > ## save this model
> > save(m1, file = "my_model1.rda")
> > 
> > ## a month later, new observations are available: 
> > newdf <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20))
> > ## load the model
> > load("my_model1.rda")
> > ## predict for the new `x`s in `newdf`
> > predict(m1, newdata = newdf)
>         1         2         3         4         5         6 
> 6.1370366 6.5631503 2.9808845 5.2464261 4.6651015 3.4475255 
>         7         8         9        10        11        12 
> 6.7961764 5.3592901 3.3691800 9.2506653 4.7562096 3.9067537 
>        13        14        15        16        17        18 
> 2.0423691 2.4764664 3.7308918 6.9999064 2.0081902 0.3256407 
>        19        20 
> 5.4247548 2.6906722
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!